# Problem with Makefile

Tags: makefile, terminal

I'm trying to compile a small program I've written for class. They have given us a Makefile to use, but it was created with Linux in mind, and I have Mac OS. Now when I run make testFills, I get this error:

```
ld: warning: directory '/lib' following -L not found
ld: library not found for -ltiff
```

Here is the important code of the actual Makefile

```
EXENAME=testFills
OBJS=testFills.o animation.o EasyBMP.o solidColorPicker.o gridColorPicker.o gradientColorPicker.o rainbowColorPicker.o
BMPDIR=../mp4_lib/include/EasyBMP
IMGMAGICKCONFIG=-I../mp4_lib/include/ImageMagick -g -O2 -Wall -W -pthread
IMGMAGICKLINKOPTS=-L../mp4_lib/lib -lMagick++ -lMagickWand -lMagickCore -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng -lfontconfig -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lbz2 -L/lib -lrsvg-2 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm  -ldl -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread
```

I have in my parent directory this mp4_lib folder, so I dont know why its saying it cant find it. Actually it cant find anyything past -ltiff in the above list. I'm new to command-line programming, so I'm not sure what this could mean or how I can fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its on the 5th line

> -lbz2 -L/lib -lrsvg-2

you probably dont have a /lib directory, it should probably be just -Llib.

/lib means that it is the root directory of your computer, rather than in the folder the makefile is in.

Comment: Alternatively you may not have tiff installed, but you can install it with macports. Then you will need -L/opt/local/lib and -I /opt/local/include

Comment: what happens if you just remove -L/lib, as there is definitely no /lib on my mac, and atleast the errors should change?

Comment: I already installed ImageMagick using ports. What would the makefile look like now to reflect the new path of ImageMagick?

Comment: all the ports installed stuff is usually located in -L/opt/local/lib (for the compiled bits) and -I /opt/local/include (for the headers). Did macports also install tiff as a dependancy to ImageMagick?

Comment: the -ltiff error is that it can't find the file libtiff.so (or .o i can't remember) in the -L directories, which sugests its not installed, whereas the others are?

Comment: How can I find out where ImageMagick was installed?

Comment: it is possible to use `pkg-config imagemagick --libs --cflags' and this will give you where all the compiler flags you need. But it was probably installed in /opt/local/lib and /opt/local/include in a directory called imagemagick or just magick

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to indicate the library "libtiff.a" path using -L option.
For example if "libtiff.a" is located in the lib directory in the parent folder of the makefile:

```
-L../lib/ -ltiff
```

will do.

For more information, see
-L explanation here :
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Directory-Options.html

and 
-l explanation here
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a configuration problem of your compiler (gcc?) installation. I've seen similar errors in faulty installations of gcc. Please, try that you can actually compile a small application.

Comment: If I want to specify a path myself, such as /users/admin/mp4_lib/lib, would I just remove that L? Not really sure what thats for

Comment: The -L tells the compiler where to look for the compiled libraries (object files) to link with the program it is compiling at the moment. (ld is the name of the linker, so its most likely that the program compiled fine, though would need to see the whole makefile to check that)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will manage to build your program if you do not have all those libraries installed (i.e. all `lLibrary` without the `l`), so look for them, and if they aren't available, install them.

Also (and I hope not to sound too obvious), if you were given some libraries for Linux (so it seems from your question), they must be built for Mac OS X in order for you to link them.

You could try to use `/usr/lib` instead of `/lib.`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/30/mac-os-x-directory-structure-explained/), the shared library folder for MacOS is at /Library.

Since your Linux Makefile said -L/lib, I think you need to change it to -L/Library, since the /lib is the shared library folder for Linux, as /Library is to Mac OS.